# Make a battleship game in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm leaning coding Ruby and trying to make a battleship game. Now I have some difficulties (found a lot of implementations at Github, but could not understand them).

I have a 10*10 board and now I'm trying to implement the algorithm of walking on the field. For example: I'm in x-position on the field, how to check the availability of A1 cell? So here is a variant... but how to make a universal method? (when I choose a position, I need to check 8 cells around for free space for the next cell).

```
def test(postition)
letter = position[0]

#   1 2 3
# A O . .
# B x . .
# C . . .

keys = board.keys
index = keys.find_index(letter)
prev_key = keys[index - 1] #up-down
unless prev_key.nil?
    is_ship_placed = board[prev_key][postition[1]] #left-right
end

#   1 2 3
# A O . .
# B . . .
# C . . .

end
```

[All my code for now is in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/PxlOAE)

I will be very grateful if someone will help me!

P.S. Excuse my english, pls.

Comment: I would start by changing how you represent the board. If you use a single array, instead of multidimensional arrays, you could just use `/` and `%` to find the position on the board. Then you can use simple addition / subtraction to find the spots surrounding that index.

Comment: So I must change this part?
 
board = {
 a: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
 b: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],

etc...

Comment: @kirbrown I just realized that Justin recommended a one-dimensional array, not the 2D array that I wrote about. Justin's 1D array is different idiom that would also work well. For example, board[23] would be row 23 / 10 = 2, and column 23 % 10 = 3. Enjoy the variety!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have expanded @JustinWood's great advice into this answer. You will find it easier to represent your board as an Array instead of a Hash.

So change

```
board = { a: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], \
          b: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false], etc.
```

to something like this two-dimensional Array. (A list of lists.)

```
board = [[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
         [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
                                     ..........                               ]]
```

Naturally you can populate it automatically instead of copy-pasting 10 rows of false into your source code. This works:

```
blank_row = Array.new(10,false)
board = Array.new(10) { blank_row.clone }
```

Then you can navigate around the board with arithmetic, to check the 8 surrounding squares.
You would do something like this:

```
def test (position)
  x, y = position 
  return true if board[y][x]
  return true if board[y-1][x-1]
  return true if board[y-1][x]
  ....
  false
end
```

Add in suitable guards to deal with the edges, and automate it instead of typing out all 9 cases.

As you noticed, when you changed the Hash to an Array, it means you have to change other parts of your game that use the board. For example, you already know how to iterate through your Hash (for example to change it)

```
board.each do |key, row|
  row.each do |v|
    # do something with cell v and build a new row
  end
  # insert the new row at board[key] 
end
```

You can iterate a 2D Array like this example

```
board.each.with_index do |row, y|
  row.each.with_index do |v, x|
    # change a true cell to 'S' and false to '.'
    if v
      board[y][x] = 'S'
    else
      board[y][x] = '.'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tnx a lot! 

But how I can change the part of code where I build the board like adding numbers, letters and change falses into dots?
And how to test my navigation?

`def test (position)
  x, y = position 
  return true if board[y][x]
  return true if board[y-1][x-1]
  return true if board[y-1][x]
  return true if board[y][x-1]
  return true if board[y+1][x+1]
  return true if board[y+1][x]
  return true if board[y][x+1]
   false
end`

And the last question, how to generally ask new questions in the theme, like my first, the comment form is not quite suitable?

Comment: @kirbrown Those are 2 new questions: the comment is definitely the wrong place. If you can't find the answer by searching, or in your Ruby tutorial, then post each one as a new question, with the shortest piece of code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I understand about publishing new questions and I will try to understand in your's proposed solution. Thank you very much! Hope, that you can possible help me some other time.